# OpenFire Rest API 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, openfire

I'm using OpenFire with the REST API plugin installed.

I'm attempting to get a list of chat rooms through an AngularJS $http call to `http://localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms`

with the proper Authorization header set in the `$http.defaults.headers.common` property.

When the call is made, I get the following error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms 401 (Unauthorized)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10722sendReq @ angular.js:10515serverRequest @ angular.js:10222processQueue @ angular.js:14745(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14761Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15989Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15800(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16028completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5507(anonymous function) @ angular.js:5784


XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://localhost:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/chatrooms. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

The truly annoying issue is, that when I build the same request through Postman, it works perfectly and the expected response is received but inside the browser (whether through $http, or a call to window.fetch  through the console) I keep getting that error.

Supposedly, the OpenFire REST API supports CORS (I went so far as to check the plugin source code), but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of REST API plugin. You are right that the REST API supports CORS, and it is possible to call it directly from angular js. The mentioned problems (preflight request) will by done by your browser. I just fixed the issue that the OPTION request don't need to auth. 
Checkout the REST API version: 1.1.7

Comment: I'm not directly creating the options call. That is created by the browser and neither I nor angular have control over that. It's created because it has an Authorization header. As I said, it works perfectly from Postman, but not from the browser.

Comment: Could you please check your plugin code? I believe your code checks for authentication even on the OPTIONS request, which cannot be done (no control over it, it is auto-generated by the browser) . You should probably exempt an OPTIONS request from authentication.

Comment: Yes, I will take look at it, and fix it.

Comment: Fixed. Checkout the REST API version: 1.1.7

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to compare the fiddler request and the browser request (headers + body). 
It should work if they are 100% identical..

Comment: That does not seem possible. A successful preflighted GET request does NOT show up as an OPTIONS request on fiddler. What fails is the actual OPTIONS request so fiddler only see it when it fails.